# Databricks: run all jobs in a queue

Tags: databricks

I have what I think is a simple ask:  I want to create a set of data bricks jobs (same job, just different parameters) and run them, but only run X at once, until all of them finish.

This is basically like using a thread pool in python.

As an example:

I have a job (or task... a notebook I want to run) `J` that takes parameter `p`, I have 100 `p` values I want to run, however I only want 10 to run at a time (say I have 10 clusters, or I want to run them all on the same cluster and that cluster needs to have enough compute to run them concurrently), however I want all 100 to eventually run.

Is this possible with Databricks?  If I submit more than the "max concurrent jobs", then the extra jobs just get skipped.  If I run multiple tasks within a single job, and they don't depend on each other, they all run at once.

What am I missing?

Comment: So you're trying to run a certain # of jobs from a total # of jobs concurrently?

Comment: I'm looking to burn through a queue of jobs.  So only a certain number of jobs concurrently and when a job is done, replace it with a new job from the queue.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the exact same problem @AndrewSpott, please add an answer if you cracked this

Comment: Have you tried/thought about a notebook that will 'orchestrate' all the runs of X notebook within a job? Written in Python with a logic that will follow the rules that you described to trigger a necessary number of notebooks with parameters that you want to use and would be doing it till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has recently introduced job queues!

[Here is the (short) documentation for it](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/create-run-jobs.html#what-if-my-job-cannot-run-because-of-concurrency-limits).

> A run is queued when one of the following limits is reached:
>
> - The maximum concurrent active runs in the workspace.
> - The maximum concurrent Run Job task runs in the workspace.
> - The maximum concurrent runs of the job.
>
> Queueing is a job-level property that queues runs only for that job.

[image] [image]